# Real-time scatter plot with D3. Having a hard time to deal with the data joining

Tags: d3.js, real-time, scatter-plot

For one of my projects, I want to create a real time scatter plot using D3. The sample rate needs to be around 30 updates per seconds. I managed to create a graph that updates itself but I am facing two issues :

1) I cannot figure out how to remove data using the exit() and remove() function
2) The page freezes up pretty quickly

I am also wondering if it was the most efficient way to create a real-time scatterplot. I have adapted code from https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/

I have looked throughout blogs and tutorials to no avail.  Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks !

EDIT : As suggested by rioV8, I ported the script to d3.v5. A few things changed but the problem is the same. If you can give me suggestion on how to make this real-time scatterplot works, that would be amazing. I realized that there is no example of such graph on internet, only line plot. Thanks !

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<script>

var n = 40,
    random = d3.randomNormal(0, .2)


var data = [{x:10,y:Math.random()},{x:15,y:Math.random()},{x:20,y:Math.random()},{x:25,y:Math.random()}];

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, n - 1])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([height, 0]);

g.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

var points = svg.selectAll("dot")
        .data(data)

points.enter().append("circle") 
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .on("start", tick);

points.exit().remove();

function tick() {

    // Push a new data point onto the back.
    data = [{x:10,y:Math.random()},{x:15,y:Math.random()},{x:20,y:Math.random()},{x:25,y:Math.random()}];
    // Redraw the line.

    console.log("bob")

    points.data(data).enter().append("circle")  
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .on("start", tick);

}

</script>
```

Comment: first have a look on how you use `transition` and how it is used in the examples, why bother the `exit` if the only thing you do is fill up to 100 samples, you change the domain of `x` only to position a new sample if not already 100 samples, how can you call `x.domain` when `x` is a local var of `scatterplot`. Why still use d3v3 for new stuff?

Comment: Comparing the gists and the code on the blog page they use very different methods of animation

Comment: Why define a `clipPath` when you don't use it? The browser locks when running your code. Have a look at the console while starting the HTML file. Read https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1642989 where do you use `d3.active`? You should only animate **1** item. Read https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/ how to use join (enter/exit/update).

Comment: Did you solve this?